# How to correctly perform an integration between lex and yacc?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

i've been trying to make a simple lexical and syntax scanner using lex and yacc, currently, the problem i'm running into is: I cannot get output any of my input into the console.

Here are the relevant parts of code:

Lex:

```
ID      {L}({L}|{D})*

%%


"let"      { return ( LET ); }
"{}"       { return ( OBJ ); }
{ID}       { return ( ID ); }
.          { return ( *yytext ); }
```

Yacc/Grammar :

```cpp
%{ 
struct Atributos {
  vector<string> c;
};
#define YYSTYPE Atributos
%}

%token ID OBJ LET

%%

Cmd : DeclVar ';' { cout << $1.c.size() << endl;}
  ;

DeclVar : LET ID '=' '{''}'  { cout << $1.c.size() << endl;}
  ;
```

I expect the $1.c be able to actually print the tokens i receive, but when I give it an input of "let a = {};" it outputs vector size as 0 always, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In neither of those production actions does `$1` refer to anything which has been given a semantic value. Terminals are given a semantic value if the scanner action assigns `yylval`. Non-terminal values are set by assigning to `$$` in the action for the non-terminal.

Comment: Shouldn't everything in DeclVar be a terminal value since they don't create new rules? I'm still trying to comprehend what $$ stands for, as I understand they are the left side of the grammar right?

Comment: Yes, the right-hand-side of `DeclVar` contains four terminals. `$1` is the semantic value corresponding to the first one, which is `LET`. There's not much point in `LET` having a semantic value, since it is purely syntactic; in that production, the only terminal which might sensibly have a semantic value is the `ID`, whose semantic value would be `$2`. However, your scanner never gives that token a semantic value. (Or any other token.) So you're not going to find anything in `$2` either. Have you tried reading the [useful manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html)?

Comment: The manual includes a number of fully explained [examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples). There's also a whole chapter on [semantic values](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics)